# how to set placeholder for images in picker view programmatically using swift

Tags: swift

I have a `pickerview` in which images are shown. I pick images from cache so it takes some time. I want when images are not loaded from a cache then my local images show there as placeholder images. when images are loaded from a cache then it shows that images.I'm new to ios development so I'm not sure about how I can show images as a placeholder in picker view.please tell me if anyone has any idea.

I have tried to set images in `viewForRow` function before it takes an image from cache. but it doesn't work.

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"no-image")
myImageView = UIImageView(image : UIImage(named: "imagename"))

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let carrier = self.carriers.object(at: row) as! NSDictionary
    vehicleName = carrier.value(forKey: kcarrierName) as! String
    vehicleID = carrier.value(forKey: kId) as! Int
    self.vehicleType.text = vehicleName
    self.currentVehicle.text = vehicleName
    self.truckType = self.vehicleType.text!
    self.truckType = self.currentVehicle.text!
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let carrier = self.carriers.object(at: row) as! NSDictionary
    vehicleImage = carrier.value(forKey: kImage) as! String
    let viewForImage = UIView()
    var myImageView = UIImageView()
    self.rotAngle = 90 * (.pi/180)
    myImageView.frame = CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width: 90, height: 90)
    myImageView.cacheImage(urlString: vehicleImage)
    myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.rotAngle)
    return myImageView
}
```

I expect  placeholder images for all images that shown in the picker view

Answer (score 0):

Assign the default image first. Then get image from cache. Till the image is downloaded from the server or fetched from the cache, the default local image will be shown

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let carrier = self.carriers.object(at: row) as! NSDictionary
    vehicleImage = carrier.value(forKey: kImage) as! String
    let viewForImage = UIView()
    var myImageView = UIImageView()
    self.rotAngle = 90 * (.pi/180)
    myImageView.frame = CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width: 90, height: 90)
    myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"no-image")
    myImageView.cacheImage(urlString: vehicleImage)
    myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.rotAngle)
    return myImageView
}
```

Comment: this didn't work.i want local placeholder images appear first then automatically images shows on that placeholder once images cached